# Does my tire need replacing?

Tags: ford, tires, sidewall-damage

[image][image][image]

I'm going to the Lake District in two days (from Cambridgeshire) and only have a day to sort this out if it needs replacing, I think the damage was caused yesterday when I accidentally hit a curb pretty hard. It is the back tire on the passenger side

Comment: Just keep your thumb out of it when you are driving and you'll be fine.

Comment: Haha, I'll try my best

Answer (score 0):

Yes, get it replaced.

Cosmetic damage to the outside of a tire (or tyre where you are) is nothing to worry about, if there's a bit hanging off you can usually glue it back into place. The main concern would be damage to the materials that give the sidewall its strength. The third picture shows that the sidewall got quite an impact and could be substantially weakened, potentially leading to a failure.

Comment: Yeah that is the outside of tyre. Thanks for your help. Any idea how much a tyre replacement normally costs? Hopefully I can get it done tomorrow, as I go away Saturday morning.

Comment: You might be able to get it done today, there are mobile tyre replacement companies that can come to you. It's probably about 30 quid maximum for the work per tyre, then the cost of the tyre on top of that. As for how much the tyre would cost I couldn't say, it depends on the car. Usually there's a range of tyres available with varying quality, I recommend not buying the cheapest available if you like staying in the road.

Comment: Might nip to my ford garage and see if they can do it this afternoon, it would be ideal. Yeah definitely won't get the cheapest, as I have a long trip in that car ahead. Thanks a lot

Comment: Dealers don't often do tyres but give it a shot. Places like halfords and Kwik-Fit might be a better bet.

Comment: Haven't been on the road for too long so not too knowledgable about this stuff, so thanks, sounds good

Comment: All Booked in and sorted. Getting it replaced this afternoon